# Cannot debug locally in Visual Studio with Docker support and Visual Studio provided SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, docker, localdb

I have a ASP.NET 5.0 Web API using Entity Framework to access SQL Server.
Running (F5) from Visual Studio works fine. The connection string is `Server=(localDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=***;Integrated Security=true`

I then add docker support. Now if I debug the app with the Docker profile I get a `System.PlatformNotSupportedException: LocalDB is not supported on this platform.`

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LocalDB is not supported on this Platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45860851/localdb-is-not-supported-on-this-platform)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LocalDB requires named pipes, which is not available in your docker (Linux) environment. Use SQL Server Express instead, and remember to enable TCP/IP protocol for remote connections.